# I want to create new database for the Discovery Service

Tags: web8, database, discovery-service

I want to create a new database for the Discovery Service, can anyone tell me if there is a script provided for this in the SDL Web 8 installation media?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-654563D2-F38B-43C9-851C-0C1104FBA2AA), you can use PowerShell, and depending on your database navigate to one of the following folders on the installation media:

- `Database\MSSQL\`
- `Database\Oracle\`

Then type the following command to create a new Discovery Service database:

`& '.\Install Content Data Store.ps1'`

If you manually want to run SQL scripts, see the following topic in the documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-40FA413B-E255-4F24-BF99-643C4124DC11

Comment: Actually I had followed the same steps & database is created identical to broker database. And I have separate broker where all published content stored.                                                                                              I have multiple discovery services approx 10 to support multiple deployers which is hosted on multiple CD servers. Is it right approach to create 10 discovery databases for each discovery service? If yes, What is the benefit of having other tables except 3 tables (configuration_value etc where actual capabilites data lies).                   Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not the right approach. If you scale out your Discovery Service, you should ensure that all instances use the same DB.

Comment: Regarding the DB schema: Discovery Service uses the same DB Schema as Content Store (aka Broker DB). This allows you to use the same DB for those two services (if you want to minimize the number of DBs). This is not recommended, though.